# How to add more text styles into android project?

Tags: textview, android

As my question. I want to change my text font in textview to something like the image below.

[image]

I don't want to use "bold" or "italic" style in textStyle.

Comment: Use `Typeface` with some font files in assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download any font file from [here](http://www.dafont.com/) and put them in fonts folder under assets folder.
And use below code for applying font on `textview` :

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Walkway Bold.ttf");
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13)).setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: Thank you but is that the only way? Can we do it in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Put the font in Assets/fonts directory and then:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourfonts.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can do it now.